# prevent other divs from moving, when resizing one div in a grid

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I may not have explained my question best in the title, but heres the issue:

i have a grid of boxes like so:[image: divs]

and when i hover on them, they resize like so:
[image]

how do i prevent the other divs from moving?

heres my code so far (color stuff is removed)

```css
.blocks {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

.block-small {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10vw;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: #808080;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.block-small:hover {
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 15%;
  ;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="blocks">
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't change the width? `width: 15%;`  Am I missing some other information or requirement that is not stated?

Comment: What do you mean by "prevent the other divs from moving?"

Comment: by "prevent the other divs from moving i meant that the otehr divs should not move to accomadate the wider length of the hovered div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest answer I can really suggest is to avoid using `width` and instead use `transform`:

```
.block-small:hover {
  transform: scaleX(150%);
}
```

This doesn't affect the sibling elements, so they won't reposition themselves in response to the change. In the demo, below, I've also added a high `z-index` in order to have the enlarged element appear above the siblings, so that content is visible.

The one problem – there is another, second, issue but that's addressed later in this answer – is that `scaleX()` (as with `scale()`, `scaleY()`) bases its percentage-measurements upon the element's own original width; whereas the `width` property – when a percentage is given – is derived from the width of the parent element. Therefore `scale(15%)` will make the element smaller.

As the `.small-block` elements are sized based on a `10%` width (of the parent), the width of the element increased by `150%` is equal to the original `15%` (of the parent) that you originally specified.

```css
.blocks {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

.block-small {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10vw;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: #808080;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.block-small:hover {
  background-color: #f00;
  transform: scaleX(150%);
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
</div>
```

Also, in turn, I'd suggest using a flex layout rather than floating your items, this allows for an easier and more consistent spacing of the items:

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.blocks {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 1%;
}

.block-small {
  border-radius: 15px;
  flex: 1 1 10%;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: #808080;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.block-small:hover {
  background-color: #f00;
  transform: scaleX(150%);
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
</div>
```

You may have noticed that the first, and last, `.small-box` element expands from the centre, and extends outside of the `.blocks` wrapper element. To fix that we can modify the `transform-origin` of those elements:

```
/* we select the .block-small element that is the
   first-child of its parent: */
.block-small:first-child {
  /* updating its transform-origin property, to have
     start at 0 (the left-most x-position) and 50%
     (the vertical-centre of the element): */
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

/* we select the .block-small element that is the
   last-child of its parent: */
.block-small:last-child {
  /* as above, but here we set its x position to
     be at the right-most position of the x-axis
     of the element: */
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.blocks {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 1%;
}

.block-small {
  border-radius: 15px;
  flex: 1 1 10%;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: #808080;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.block-small:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

.block-small:last-child {
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

.block-small:hover {
  background-color: #f00;
  transform: scaleX(150%);
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
  <div class="block-small"></div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).
- [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin).

Comment: just what i was looking for!
also for some reason scaleX(150%) doesnt seem to work for me (on chrome, windows)
anyway i fixed it by setting it to scaleX(1.5)

Answer (score 0):

You can try resizing other divs when they are not hovered. And only resize the div that is hovered

```css
.blocks {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

.block-small {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10vw;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: #808080;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
.blocks:hover>div {
  width: 9.65%;
}
.blocks>div:hover {
  width:15%;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the CSS that changes the width: here I commented it out for clarity

```css
.blocks {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

.block-small {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10vw;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: #808080;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.block-small:hover {
  background-color: #f00;
 /* width: 15%; */
  ;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="blocks">
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
    <div class="block-small"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```